How can we dim the entire scrollable screen in ionic
In ion content , there are  cards , when I long press , the cards should be highlited , for that , I have used dimming effect , when I long press , the screen will be dimmed  , but  the ion content is scrollable , the  dimming is not happening for whole screen , how can we do that.
This is the ccss I have used for dimming
.dim-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
  z-index: 10; 
}

I need the whole screen to be dimmed when I long press, please let me know if there is any solution

Try the below CSS. Maybe the height and width set to 100% it causes a smaller overlay to be created. Instead we rely on the window size and set the corners to 0, as seen below and it should cover the entire visible screen.
.dim-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
  z-index: 10; 
}

